# Azure website dashboard stopped logging requests

Tags: azure

For the last day our Azure website (www.rockrms.com) has been experiencing extremely slow response times and frequent 502 (Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server) errors.  What's strange also is that our Azure website dashboard has stopped reporting any activity even though we can still get to the site (if you're patient)...

[image]

We did deploy an update around the time that this started happening, but not sure if or how that could be causing issues since the site is working (but painfully slow) or how it could have affected the logging of requests or server errors.

We've tried restarting the website, redeploying, and turning on detailed error messages, but nothing seems to help.  Is there anything else we can look at or configure in Azure that would give us some indication of what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our issue was resolved by making the change suggested by this comment [in this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8f6fc304-75b0-4c2c-bd8d-5caa507c66da/azure-website-constantly-restarts-due-to-slow-requests-limit?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreviewhttp://):

We have identified this issue as a bug in new Auto-Heal feature we shipped recently. Please add following in your web.config file to mitigate this issue for now.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <monitoring>
           <triggers>
                <slowRequests timeTaken="02:00:00" count="1000000000" timeInterval="00:01:00" />
           </triggers>
           <actions value="LogEvent" />
      </monitoring>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```